# django-storages + sorl_thumbnail + S3 not working well together (URLs mismatch)

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, sorl-thumbnail, django-storage

I am using django-storages and sorl_thumbnail together and I am using Amazon S3 for static and media files. I am using one bucket with 2 folders, 1 for static and 1 for media.

Here is my config:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/static/'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'my_lib.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'my_lib.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
```

`MediaRootS3BotoStorage` and `StaticRootS3BotoStorage` are defined like this:

```
StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
```

When I am using sorl_thumbnail, the thumbnails generated are located in the right directory: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/media/cache` but when sorl_thumbnail is trying to retrieve an already existing thumbnail, the URL generated is: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/cache`, you will notice that the `media` folder is omitted.

Do you have any idea how I could fix that?

I know I could just use django-storages and have my static and media files all mixed up in my bucket, but that's a bit too dirty for my taste :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to make it work by defining **MediaRootS3BotoStorage** and **StaticRootS3BotoStorage** as follows:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
from django.conf import settings

class StaticRootS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    Storage for static files.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['location'] = 'static'
        super(StaticRootS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class MediaRootS3BotoStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    """
    Storage for uploaded media files.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['location'] = 'media'
        super(MediaRootS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This link can be helpful https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage

Comment: The `super()` methods on each of the `__init__()` methods above are calling the wrong classes.

They should be:

`super(StaticRootS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

and

`super(MediaRootS3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and the solution by Salma Hamed turned out to be the right one for me.

Before we had

```
StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
```

which resulted in the wrong 'storage' values in our thumbnail_kvstore table. This lambda definition does not create a new class and thus type(StaticRootS3BotoStorage()) returns 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage', which is written into the table. Because these 'storage' values are used to instantiate later the storage in order to get the image URLs when displaying, this resulted in S3BotoStorage() to be used for this. So the 'location' argument was lost.

The solution by Salma Hamed that defines these custom storages as classes fixes this.

Thanks for that!

Comment: Do you remember where you learnt to use the previous solution of `lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')`? I would like to go post a comment or correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting THUMBNAIL_PREFIX to media/cache/?

http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html#thumbnail-prefix

Comment: Yes, I have already tried, thank you. But it doesn't work either, the problem will be the same, for example if I set `/media/cache` when the files are pushed the url will be `/media/media/cache`, wand when retrieved `/media/cache`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem but I figured out a way around it.

I set my `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` back to `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage`, that way, when it looked for `cache/` it would not miss, and I could still upload all of my files to `media/`, and `python manage.py collectstatic` still works properly because I still have that set as `StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')`.

Hope this help you, because this problem was driving me crazy.

Comment: thank you for your help! But the result for me when I use these settings are the static files go the the /static/ folder on S3 but all the uploaded files are in the root folder, they don't go in /media/. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but make sure that in your models you are using `UPLOAD_TO='media/'`. That should put your uploaded files where you want them.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that that you were doing, but I would prefer not, else it just breaks the purpose of how django works :) Thank you anyway!

Comment: @e-Jah did u find a solution, coz I am facing the same problem

Comment: @SalmaHamed: unfortunately my solution has been to switch to my own server(s), it fixes so much trouble!

Comment: @e-Jah did u switch the amazon s3 or ur main server or all of them :) ??. Because my current combination of server(S) are: Heroku + Amason s3
because personally I thought, it has nothing to do with the server. and it's a sorl-thumbnail url translation problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Found that `sorl-thumbnail` is returning the cached `KV` image `url` using `STATIC_URL` (on the next request after the initial thumbnail is created). Appears `MEDIA_URL` has no affect.

Not the best solution. Added a `S3` routing rule.

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>cache/</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>media/cache/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Answer (score 0):

IDK why but @SalmaHamed 's solution didn't work for me (Maybe its because of change in the django version or something). Instead, I replaced: `MediaRootS3BotoStorage  = lambda: S3Boto3Storage(location='media')` with: `class MediaRootS3BotoStorage(S3Boto3Storage):  location = 'media'`